# Connect Postgresql database remote server ubuntu server (Docker-Compose) and Node.js express backend

Tags: node.js, postgresql, flutter, docker, express

I have a small personal project of Flutter application with Node.js express backend and a Postgresql database.

For the moment my database is hosted on my pc locally but having an ubuntu server I would like my database on it.

So I created a Docker container with my Postgresql database in it.

However I'm a bit stuck now I don't know how to create a database instance on my remote server and make it communicate with my application...

Here is my ormconfig.ts file i suppose i have to change here...

```
import { join } from "path";
import {ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";
import { PostEntity } from "./database/entity/post.entity";
import { UserEntity } from "./database/entity/user.entity";

const connectionOptions : ConnectionOptions = {

    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432
    username:"postgres",
    password:"pg",
    database:"test",
    entities: [UserEntity,PostEntity],
    synchronize:true,
    dropSchema:false,
    migrationsRun:true,
    logging:false,
    logger:"debug",
    migrations:[join(__dirname,"src/migration/**/*.ts")],


};

export = connectionOptions;
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please add more information to help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: there is no real problem I'm just looking to understand how to connect my database to my app, if you have any tutorial or link, I will appreciate, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of your network setup with your Ubuntu server, but realistically it should be something like:

```js
import { join } from "path";
import {ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";
import { PostEntity } from "./database/entity/post.entity";
import { UserEntity } from "./database/entity/user.entity";

const connectionOptions : ConnectionOptions = {

    type: "postgres",
    host: UBUNTU_SERVER_ADDRESS,
    port: POSTGRES_DOCKER_PORT
    username:"postgres",
    password:"pg",
    database:"test",
    entities: [UserEntity,PostEntity],
    synchronize:true,
    dropSchema:false,
    migrationsRun:true,
    logging:false,
    logger:"debug",
    migrations:[join(__dirname,"src/migration/**/*.ts")],


};

export = connectionOptions;
```

You'll need to make sure that the Postgres Docker instance has opened ports to connect to. E.g.:

```sh
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 ...other-args postgres:latest
```

Make sure your Ubuntu server has correctly configured firewall and network settings to allow remote access on port 5432.

Comment: Thanks I will try this as soon as possible !